How to render Rich Text from Strapi in Blazor?
I am trying to render Rich Text (Block) in Blazor WASM but it is not loading any data from Strapi. Problem is definitly in loading RICH TEXT from Strapi.
This is my html code for rendering Rich Text (Block):
<div class="w-full">
    @if (postDetails.Data.Content?.Count > 0)
        {
           <p class="rounded h-40 w-full object-cover object-center mb-6" src="@postDetails.Data.Content[0].Children" alt="content">
           </p>
        }
</div>

And full c# code:
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    private PostSingle postDetails = null;

    public string strapi_api_url;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        strapi_api_url = Configuration["AppSettings:STRAPI_API_URL"];
        var url = "{STRAPI_API_URL}/api/posts/{Id}?populate=*"; // Specify media population
        url = url.Replace("{STRAPI_API_URL}", strapi_api_url);
        url = url.Replace("{Id}", Id);
        postDetails = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<PostSingle>(url);

        if (postDetails.Data != null)
        {
            if (postDetails.Data.Image != null)
            {
                foreach (var media in postDetails.Data.Image)
                {
                    media.Url = strapi_api_url + media.Url;
                }
            }
            if (postDetails.Data.Content != null)
            {
                foreach (var text in postDetails.Data.Content)
                {
                    text.Children = strapi_api_url + text.Children;
                }
            }
        }
    }

I tried to debug the code, and everything else was working fine. I tried to handle it in code in same way as title, but it wasn't working. Gemini and Chat GPT does not help me. Can someone help me, thanks.
